# OS-Prober doesn't show my Windows 7 partition

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, uefi, windows-7

I'm having a problem installing Ubuntu 12.04 on my ASUS UX31A alongside Windows 7; I tried to launch `os-prober` in my terminal and the only option I get is:

```
/dev/sda5:Windows Recovery Environment (loader):Windows1:chain
```

while Windows 7 (mounted on `dev/sda3`) is not shown.

This is what I see in my Disk Manager in Windows 7:

[image: Disk Manager]

C: basically is the partition with Windows system's file, while the D: one is for data), while this is what I see when I launch GParted:

[image: GParted]

May it be because Windows is installed on SSD? How do I know that? Is it safe if I proceed with the installation for computers with UEFI, SSD and HDD? I'm not sure that's my case.

Answer (score 0):

You are using MS-DOS partition table created by Windows 7, and the maximum allowed [primary partitions are 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record#Sector_layout). There are no extended partitions on your system. So when you select "Install along side windows" it tries to create a primary partition and fails.

You should make a new partition table like I've done on my HDD.

My partition table with /dev/sda1 as primary and /dev/sda2 as extended partition.

[image: My partition table with /dev/sda1 as primary and /dev/sda2 as extended]

Comment: when I try to install Ubuntu, it doesn't give me the option "Install alongside Windows 7"